# JVM SIGSEGV crash in native without any named library

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-crash

We've now encountered two times a SIGSEGV crash in Oracle 1.8.0_60 JVM where the error log doesn't even implicate any library, just says that crash happened in native code:

```
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007f6d04000000
#
```

and

```
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007fc6ec048ff0
#
```

Both times the thread that crashes is an application thread. Either a `ForkJoinPool` or Tomcat ajp-bio thread.

What could've gone wrong? Normally when there's a failure in native libraries, there's a name of the library included.
What I see in sanitized hs_err-logs for [the first crash](https://gist.github.com/jmiettinen/9547532b50236967c38129c6b94ae291) and [the second crash](https://gist.github.com/jmiettinen/498abdc7f47c6baa7675ef9a22d7f747) ([full version for comparison](https://gist.github.com/jmiettinen/c1c1da647ce7d562acb0ee000c332e7c)) doesn't give me much more ideas about what could've gone wrong as there seems to be enough memory. Just the metaspace is even near to running out.

The environment runs on 64-bit Linux:

```
[foo@bar ~]$ uname -a
Linux bar 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 22 06:48:29 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I would try Java 8 update 92 just in case this helps and see if you can work out the thread name as a clue to what is crashing.

Comment: Show us full crash dumps. Otherwise there will be just random guesses.

Comment: Sorry, I had broken the links in my formatting changes. `hs_err`-logs are now linked properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only posted one full log so it's not really possible to spot a pattern here, but the C frame is in a non-executable memory region and outside the code space.  The VM events also show a flurry of re/deoptimizations and a bias revocation. So my guess is that might be a miscompilation.

Things you can try:

1. update your JVM. `8.0_60-b27` is not the latest patch level.
2. try `-XX:-UseBiasedLocking -XX:-TieredCompilation`
3. try `-XX:-UseBiasedLocking -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1`

If updating the vm does not fix it but one of the options does then it's probably a VM bug and you should file with your linux distribution or oracle.

Comment: In the [other case](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jmiettinen/dde6adb59e31f2de6171bd5af0101ac1/raw/fce0bbebed0eed5475d5d2a013ff774e1738bb49/hs_err_full.log) the situation seems to be the same except there are no deoptimizations.

Thanks for your help! Now I'll just have to come up with a way to get this reproduced in such a way that Oracle could take a look at it.